# Xpath doesn't match

Tags: python, html, xpath, lxml, html5lib

I'm trying to get some elements from a page. Unfortunately it results with an empty list. The pretty-printed tree includes this element:

```
<html:a title="..." href="..." id="..." class="topic_title">...</html:a>
```

However when I do this on the same tree:

```
page.xpath('''.//a[@class="topic_title"]''')
```

I get an empty list. The tree was created with html5lib / lxml treebuilder.

Answer (score 2):

It seems as if you are dealing with XHTML, so you could register the namespace `html` before evaluating the XPath expression:

```
page.xpath('''.//html:a[@class="topic_title"]''',
           namespaces={'html': 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml'})
```

See also [Namespaces and Prefixes](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#namespaces-and-prefixes):

> If your XPath expression uses namespace prefixes, you must define them in a prefix mapping. To this end, pass a dictionary to the namespaces keyword argument that maps the namespace prefixes used in the XPath expression to namespace URIs.